# How do I make sure that my cancelled to zero Mathjax term is in the same line (same height) as the rest of the terms (text)?

Tags: html, mathjax

```
<span> 
Integrating the correct simplified continuity equation, we obtain \(v(y) = constant\). In general, \(v = v(x,y,z,\cancelto{0}{t})\)but we can apply the following assumptions: 
</span>
```

Result shown in picture below (notice how the cancelled to zero 't' is out of place):
[image]

Do note that this is only a snippet of my code for a HTML webpage. I am parsing all of the math terms using MathJax.

Comment: Are you sure you are actually using latex and not, say, mathjax?

Comment: Oh yes, this code I posted is only part of a HTML webpage that I am deploying. You are  right. I am parsing all of my math terms using mathjax. 

Is this the reason why it is showing up like this? Any solutions?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Comment: mathjax does not actually use latex, it merely emulates a subset of the synatx. I changed the tags to make sure your question attracts the attention of people who actually know the involved technology.